# NuGet restore during first asp.net vNext project

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core

Today I [installed ASP.NET 5 on windows](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html) and [begun creating my first application](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html) in Visual Studio 2015.

When the project loads I get an error: "Package restore failed", specifically the following error:

```
Restore failed Det gick inte att hitta en del av s�kv�gen C:\Users\h\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.4.0.0.nupkg.sha512. NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\h\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
    C:\Users\h\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NextTest\nuget.config
Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU
```

When I look for the missing file I find the following path missing:

```
C:\Users\h\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.4.0.0.nupkg.sha512
```

But this one exists, note the extra 0 in the version:

```
C:\Users\h\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.0.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.4.0.0.0.nupkg.sha512
```

**How would I go about to solve this?**

I've tried to search through the project files but no mention of neither Primitives nor verion 4.0.0.

The "Solution DNX SDK version" is 1.0.0-beta8, (beta5 was also available but not selected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete C:\Users\h.dnx\packages folder and try running "dnu restore" command.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I'll accept this as an answer once the timer allows.